# The button I created is showing up in preview but not on the application

Tags: android, xml

So, I created a button using the Palette and it's displayed on the preview but not when I run my application, here is a screen shot of the preview: https://i.gyazo.com/2865a486d2c73e7b3e1994ff9106ba67.png

Here's my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_student_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="something.somethingelse">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
        android:onClick="doSomething()"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```